# Can someone tell me how to use basic set notation to say...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A is a set of integers that are not divisible by 3 except the numbers 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, and 39.

I'm working on some challenge problems that require set notation and I think I may have it but I could be wrong:

{A | A is in ℤ, 3∤ℤ, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39}

How does that look? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:(3\not|n)\vee(n\in\{21,24,27,30,33,36,39\})\}$$

Comment: why would I use n not A?

Comment: @bbuddy27: $A$ is a set. $n$ is an element in the set.